# GraphQL rendering a Rich Text editor - array?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I got on GraphCMS schema a **Rich text** with id *contentField*.
I got this query:

```
    {
  portfolios {
    id
    slug
    contentField {
      raw
    }
  }
}
```

and output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "portfolios": [
      {
        "id": "cky8wkngw6uvu0c12oos7hubg",
        "slug": "test-title-1",
        "contentField": {
          "raw": {
            "children": [
              {
                "type": "paragraph",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "text": "Ocieplanie podłogowe - Nagawczyna"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "src": "https://media.graphcms.com/7RZKcf2521521saUlOeA",
                "type": "image",
                "title": "divider-1526808_1920.jpg",
                "width": 1920,
                "handle": "7RZKcf6RhmF7QbqUlOeA",
                "height": 1440,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "text": ""
                  }
                ],
                "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
              },
              {
                "type": "paragraph",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "text": ""
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
```

How can I render in my React app a whole contentField with all the childrens of raw? I got there texts, images etc. I would like to render the whole content at once:

```
    export default function Portfolio({ portfolioItem }) {
  console.log(portfolioItem);
  const router = useRouter();
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <Section>
      <Box>
        {portfolioItem.title}
        <Image
          src={portfolioItem.coverImage.url}
          width={1200}
          height={800}
          alt={portfolioItem.title}
        />
        {portfolioItem.contentField.raw} //  HERE I AM !! HERE I AM !!
      </Box>
    </Section>
  );
}
```

and here is an error: ***"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."***

edit 11.01.2022: do I have to use Slate framework?: https://docs.slatejs.org/concepts/09-rendering

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Rich Text you have to handle the different types of your content. As you can see your content is `raw` means you need to handle the HTML in the case it will be a paragraph, a header, a image and so on.

You can use your own solution but is often brittle and not very secure. You can easily forget some case and your app will crash.
If you don't have a very custom content I would recommend you to use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@graphcms/rich-text-react-renderer

You simply pass your `contentField.raw` to `content` props

Otherwise, even simpler but not always fully working, you can try returning `html` instead of `raw` and see if it display good enough for you:
https://graphcms.com/blog/working-with-the-graphcms-rich-text-field#html

So in your query you will do

```
    {
  portfolios {
    id
    slug
    contentField {
      html
    }
  }
}
```

and in your react component:
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: yourQuery.contentField.html}} />`